# What are the hitboxes in Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

Different shooters treat shooting different parts of the body differently.

Many Call of Duty titles only separate the body into two areas: the head, and everything else (with the exception of sniper rifles). On the other hand, I believe that in Battlefield titles you do more damage to the body than to the limbs.

How does this work in Star Wars Battlefront? Do I do more damage hitting the chest than the feet? Does it depend on which weapon I'm using?

Answer (score 2):

I am 100% sure that damage to the head does more damage than damage to the rest of the body. For example, one melee hit to the head will kill instantly at full health, whereas hitting another part of the body will not kill (usually drops to around 70-80% health.)

The gun you are using will definitely effect how much damge you do whilst shooting. Some guns do a lot more damage at closer range, such as the DL-44 blaster pistol.

As Battlefront is ran on the same engine as Battlefield, and bullet drop and accuracy is treated in the same manner, I would expect that the hit boxes would be the same too.

Comment: That's good to know that it's the same engine. I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score -2):

In my own experience, I beleive that it just separates head from everything else, since shooting enemies in the feet kills them as quickly as shooting in the chest.

Comment: When you say "as quickly", have you actually checked and counted the shots in a controlled situation?